# Extract with JSON_QUERY

Tags: json, oracle

The JSON string we have stored in the table has this format to it:

```
[
   {
      "itemid" : "18726539",
      "duration" : "19:28",
      "title" : "Flight Plan for Trading: Market Lessons from My Pilot Dad",
      "description" : "<p>Learning to fly an airplane can build an excellent structured thought process for navigating markets</p>",
      "pubDate" : "Wed, 14 Apr 2021 18:04:19 +0000"
   }
]
```

When I test it with IS JSON, all the data comes back.  So, Oracle is seeing this as JSON.   However, I'm not sure how to get the "itemid" and "description" items.   I tried this query, but it comes up empty:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(json_str, '$.itemid' RETURNING  VARCHAR2(30)  WITH ARRAY WRAPPER) AS overview FROM json_podcast_data;
```

I'm thinking that the leading bracket might be causing an issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because there's no `itemid` property of the root element (an array). You need to access this property of the first item, so should be `$[0].itemid` or `$[*].itemid` to throw the error if the array contains more than one item. See [Basic SQL/JSON Path Expression Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618)

Comment: Awesome.   Thank you much.   This is good to know for future references.......

Comment: Bigger picture - you are trying to use `JSON_QUERY`, and it is not clear why. `JSON_QUERY` extracts a JSON fragment from your input. In your example, you are trying to extract two atomic values ("scalars") - exactly what `JSON_QUERY` does ***not*** do. Use `JSON_VALUE` twice, or (better!) a single call to `JSON_TABLE`, as shown in the answers. Do use `JSON_QUERY` if you have an array of more than one object, and you need to extract attributes from **all** array members in a single pass; but if that is your actual use case, your example didn't show that.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using multiple `JSON_VALUE` functions, you can use a single `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT j.itemid,
       j.duration,
       j.title,
       j.description,
       TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         j.pubdate,
         'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
       ) AS pubdate
FROM   json_podcast_data d
       CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
         d.json_str,
         '$[*]'
         ERROR ON ERROR
         COLUMNS(
           itemid      VARCHAR2(20)   PATH '$.itemid',
           duration    VARCHAR2(10)   PATH '$.duration',
           title       VARCHAR2(200)  PATH '$.title',
           description VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.description',
           pubdate     VARCHAR2(50)   PATH '$.pubDate'
         )
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE json_podcast_data (json_str CLOB CHECK (json_str IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO json_podcast_data ( json_str ) VALUES (
'[
   {
      "itemid" : "18726539",
      "duration" : "19:28",
      "title" : "Flight Plan for Trading: Market Lessons from My Pilot Dad",
      "description" : "<p>Learning to fly an airplane can build an excellent structured thought process for navigating markets</p>",
      "pubDate" : "Wed, 14 Apr 2021 18:04:19 +0000"
   }
]' );
```

Outputs:

> | ITEMID | DURATION | TITLE | DESCRIPTION | PUBDATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 18726539 | 19:28 | Flight Plan for Trading: Market Lessons from My Pilot Dad | Learning to fly an airplane can build an excellent structured thought process for navigating markets | 2021-04-14 18:04:19.000000 +00:00 |

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the itemid and description using `JSON_VALUE`. See example below

```sql
WITH
    json_podcast_data (json_str)
    AS
        (SELECT '[
   {
      "itemid" : "18726539",
      "duration" : "19:28",
      "title" : "Flight Plan for Trading: Market Lessons from My Pilot Dad",
      "description" : "<p>Learning to fly an airplane can build an excellent structured thought process for navigating markets</p>",
      "pubDate" : "Wed, 14 Apr 2021 18:04:19 +0000"
   }
]'
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT json_value (json_str, '$[0].itemid')          AS itemid,
       json_value (json_str, '$[0].description')     AS description
  FROM json_podcast_data;


     ITEMID                                                                                                    DESCRIPTION
___________ ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
18726539    <p>Learning to fly an airplane can build an excellent structured thought process for navigating markets</p>
```

If your JSON array has multiple items in it, you can use the `JSON_TABLE` function to list all items in the array.

```sql
/* Formatted on 27-Jul-2021 5:51:38 PM (QP5 v5.354) */
WITH
    json_podcast_data (json_str)
    AS
        (SELECT '[
   {
      "itemid" : "18726539",
      "duration" : "19:28",
      "title" : "Flight Plan for Trading: Market Lessons from My Pilot Dad",
      "description" : "<p>Learning to fly an airplane can build an excellent structured thought process for navigating markets</p>",
      "pubDate" : "Wed, 14 Apr 2021 18:04:19 +0000"
   },
   {
      "itemid" : "23456",
      "duration" : "10:15",
      "title" : "Test Title",
      "description" : "<p>Some cool podcast</p>",
      "pubDate" : "Wed, 14 Apr 2021 18:04:19 +0000"
   }
]'
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT j.itemid, j.description
  FROM json_podcast_data
       CROSS JOIN
       JSON_TABLE (
           json_str,
           '$[*]'
           COLUMNS itemid NUMBER PATH '$.itemid', description VARCHAR2 PATH '$.description') j;


     ITEMID                                                                                                    DESCRIPTION
___________ ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
   18726539 <p>Learning to fly an airplane can build an excellent structured thought process for navigating markets</p>
      23456 <p>Some cool podcast</p>
```